# Refresh setInterval on Hover

Tags: jquery, time, hover, setinterval, mouseenter

I have a setInterval() function which simply every four seconds change picture on my page by simply operarating with one value.

```
setInterval(function(){
    changeSlide(slideNumber);
    slideNumber++;
    if(slideNumber===5)slideNumber=0;
},4000);
```

As you see , this value is slideNumber.

Now, what I want:

When you move mouseenter on element(lets say id="hoverElement") , the interval must stop, because the picture must stay in place, and my changeSlide shows and hide those pictures.

And when you mouseleave, it waits those 4000 ms and continue.

How can I do it?

EDIT:

Sorry, it doesnt work

This is my code

```
function slide(){
    slideTimer = setInterval(function(){
        changeSlide(slideNumber);
        slideNumber++;
        if(slideNumber===5)slideNumber=0;
    },4000);
}

slide();

$('#hoverElement').mouseenter(function(){
    clearInterval(slideTimer);
    console.log('mouseenter');
});
$('#hoverElement').mouseleave(function(){
    slide();
    console.log('mouseleave');
});
```

Almost this same, and it doesnt stops the interval on mouseenter. I tried your code before, and it doesnt worked either.

Answer (score 2):

Just start and clear the interval on hover :

```
var timer, slideNumber = 0;

function slide() {
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        changeSlide(slideNumber);
        slideNumber++;
        if(slideNumber===5) slideNumber=0;
    },4000);
}

function unslide() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}

slide();

$('#hoverElement').on({
    mouseenter: unslide,
    mouseleave: slide
});
```

Here's a [**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/TQLdD/) to show it working !